# In Codeception, what's the difference between defining helper methods in Unit.php and UnitTester.php?

Tags: codeception

In Codeception unit tests, all `public` methods defined in `Unit.php` and `UnitTester.php` are available in `$this->tester`.

#### Some of the support files for Codeception unit tests:

```
tests/_support/_generated/UnitTesterActions.php
tests/_support/Helper/Unit.php
tests/_support/UnitTester.php
```

`$this->tester` is an instance of `UnitTester`. `UnitTester.php` `use`s `_generated\UnitTesterActions` which itself embeds the methods from `Unit.php` into it when the tests are initialised. Apart from the IDE not being able to resolve the methods in `$this->tester` until the tests have been run, what's the difference? Is there a best practice or is it simply a matter of taste? Why are there two different ways to do the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

Actually I don't know why it is possible to add methods to UnitTester class, but they are less reusable.

Methods defined in Helper classes can be used in different suites, by enabling them as modules.
There is no reason to restrict Helper names to suite names, you can have specialized well-named helpers like Helper\Authentication, Helper\Rainbow, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your work on answering these questions. I get so confused trying to understand helpers. That last sentence should be in the manual!!!